# Is there a way to prevent changing the MAC address on a Windows machine?

Tags: windows, mac-address

Is it possible to stop someone from changing the MAC address of a Windows machine using [GPOs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy)?

Comment: On Windows I believe it requires administrator rights anyway. Don't give your users admin rights and you should be safe. Of course, if MAC spoofing is a risk it suggests there's a bigger problem somewhere else.

Comment: Don't have any network interfaces and you won't be able to change their MACs.

Comment: Do you know how MAC's are spoofed on windows? finding the answer out for that question may help you with this one ;)

Comment: @Sighbah no I don't know how they are spoofed on Windows, but I've seen how easy it is to do on Linux.  (But ya do have to be root!)

Comment: Haha im not sure either tbh never really had a reason to do it on a windows machine. Having a quick google it seems this is achieved by changing the network address on the adapter properties, so rolling out a GPO with restricition to the adapter properties either in the user or machine policy would probably restrict the ease this can be done.

Answer (score 3):

(There may be network cards which use a fixed MAC address, but I've not yet heard of them.)

As the comments suggest, an Administrator account in Windows can adjust the MAC address, as well as the IP address. A non-administrator account cannot. So, if you do not trust the user, or want to reduce the risk of viruses, you should certainly run a non-administrator account.

However, with physical access to the machine, there are many possible ways to bypass the user account controls, and gain administrator access anyway. Properly securing a machine when someone has physical access is quite complex and depends on the specific requirements.

And besides that, could someone just unplug the network cable and plug it into a a separate device for which they have root access?

The best thing to do would be to have a middle-man device which controls the traffic. For example, with a Managed Switch, each PC can be plugged into a separate port. The physical port number can be tied to a specific IP address and MAC address requirement.

Besides a proper Managed Switch, many Routers, or small computers with multiple ethernet ports have the ability to enforce such restrictions.

(Finally, were you to use a Proxy or NAT, then the MAC address would be reset in that way, but this is probably not what you are looking for.)

Comment: Actually, a proxy is exactly why I'm interested in this.  I'm filtering internet access with pfSense.

Comment: If you use a Proxy, why do you care what the MAC address is? Is it to control whether they get access to the Proxy?

Comment: It's to control which users get to access which sites at which times...I'm aware that there's probably a way to do this with usernames too but I'm not there yet.

Comment: Don't use MAC addresses for any sort of access control - it's really not a strict identifier